# How can I get hour/minute from TimePicker

Tags: android, timepicker

I have a layout where I placed a TimePicker and two buttons for select time:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical"
        >
    <TimePicker android:id="@+id/time_picker"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
        >
    <Button android:id="@+id/time_picker_ok"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/yes"
            android:onClick="set"/>
    <Button android:id="@+id/time_picker_cancel"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/no"
            android:onClick="cancel"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

I call it through method from another activity:

```
public void showPicker(View view) {
    LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    View dialogView = li.inflate(R.layout.time_picker, null);
    dialogView = new TimePicker(this);

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle(R.string.time_start_label);
    builder.setView(dialogView);

    ad = builder.create();
    ad.show();
}
```

And I have a handler for "yes" button:

```
public void set(View view) {
    LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) li.inflate(R.layout.time_picker, null);
    TimePicker tp = (TimePicker) ll.findViewById(R.id.time_picker);
    int hour = tp.getCurrentHour();
    int minute = tp.getCurrentMinute();

    Utils.showMessage(this, hour + " " + minute); // Toast message
}
```

But when I click on @+id/time_picker_ok I get a current system time instead of a selected time.

How can I get selected time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

getCurrentXXX() is supposed to answer the current hour or minute.

To read the time entered by the user, you have to use a listener like this:

```
// the callback received when the user "sets" the time in the dialog
private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener mTimeSetListener =
    new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            mHour = hourOfDay;
            mMinute = minute;
            updateDisplay();
        }
    };
```

See this tutorial for more details: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-timepicker.html

Answer (score 0):

### Simple Method for Getting Date and Time from a DatePicker a TimePicker

*Caveat: it uses **JodaTime's** `DateTime` as the return. You can modify it to use whatever you like.*

```
 // Gets the Date and Time from a DatePicker and TimePicker and return a JodaTime DateTime from them, in current timezone.
 //
 private DateTime getDateTimeFromPickers( int DatePickerId, int TimePickerId ) {
     DatePicker dp = (DatePicker) findViewById(DatePickerId);
     TimePicker tp = (TimePicker) findViewById(TimePickerId);

     String year    = Integer.toString(dp.getYear()) ;
     String month   = StringUtils.leftPad( Integer.toString(dp.getMonth() + 1), 2, "0" );
     String day     = StringUtils.leftPad( Integer.toString(dp.getDayOfMonth()), 2, "0" );
     String hour    = StringUtils.leftPad( Integer.toString(tp.getCurrentHour()), 2, "0" );
     String minutes = StringUtils.leftPad( Integer.toString(tp.getCurrentMinute()), 2, "0" );

     String dateTime = year + "-" + month + "-" + day + "T" + hour + ":" + minutes + ":00.000";

     return DateTime.parse(dateTime);
 }
```

Hope that helps.

JP